# How can I group numbers and words?

Tags: c#, .net

`string str = "We have 23 students at Cybernetics, 32 students at Computer Science and we also have 12 teachers";`

I need to extract the number of students and teachers from the string.
There will be a list of keywords for which I will need to count the total number.

```
string input = "We have 23 students at Cybernetics, 32 students at Computer Science and we also have 12 teachers";

        List<string> keywords = new List<string>();
        keywords.Add("teacher");
        keywords.Add("student");
        keywords.Add("kid");
        keywords.Add("parent");

        foreach(var k in keywords)
        {
            if (input.Contains(k))
            {
                ????
            }
        }
```

> Output: 55 students, 12 teachers.

Comment: What is the exact format for the text? Are "Number of students: 123" or "We have a total of 120 people, including 13 teachers" valid inputs? Are you trying to sum numbers that occur before all occurrences of a particular keyword?

Comment: I'm belive that to solve this you need to build AI. What numbers should be extracted from "All teachers and 12 students work together"? Human can say that students count is 12 and teachers count is unknown. To provide same answer your program should be able to understand natural language

Comment: you may need to use some regexes. First one : \d.* 'keyword' and after that you can use, \d* and add all the matches converted to integer.

Comment: One simple way to do this: split your sentence in words. For each 'students' or 'teachers' word, pick the previous word and parse it to a number.

Comment: @someone, I'm trying to sum the numbers for particular keywords. For example:"I need 1 apple, 3 tomatoes, 5 carrots,  2 apples, 1 tomato ." Expected output: 3 apple, 4 tomatoes, 5 carrots

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example without regexes, you can adapt it to support teachers, parents,...:

```
    string input = "We have 23 students at Cybernetics, 32 students at Computer Science and we also have 12 teachers";
    var words = input.Split(' ');
    int studentCount = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<words.Length; i++)
    {
        string word = words[i];
        int nr;
        if(int.TryParse(word, out nr))
        {
            if(i+1 < words.Length && words[i+1] == "students") studentCount+=nr;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Students " + studentCount);
```

Link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jMzPr9

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete Regex solution

```
string input = @"We have 23 students at Cybernetics, 32 students at Computer Science and we also have 12 teachers";

List<string> keywords = new List<string>();
keywords.Add("student");
keywords.Add("teacher");
keywords.Add("kid");
keywords.Add("parent");

foreach(var k in keywords)
{
    string pattern = @"(\d*) "+k;
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
    int total = 0;
    foreach (Match match in matches) {
        total+= Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[1].Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(total + " " + k+", ");
}
```

Comment: var filteredString = 'sdasda alskdamkdsa start 3 saadasda apples asac a a end aksnasj asknan aksna start 5 potatoes end'
var pattern = /(?<=start\s).*(?=end)/g;
var matches = pattern.exec(filteredString);
alert(matches);  I want to obtain two substrings: from start => to end. So first should be = '3 saadasda apples asac a a'; and second = '5 potatoes'. The current output is: '3 saadasda apples asac a a end aksnasj asknan aksna start 5 potatoes'